# Обновление AbstractTableModel после десериализации при помощи gson

Tags: java, swing, gson, десериализация

Имеется графический интерфейс для работы с ArrayList который выводится в виде таблицы. Для этого я использую AbstractTableModel. Реализованы кнопки добавить, удалить, сохранить и загрузить. Вся проблема в кнопке загрузить. После того как я десериализую по кнопке мой список из файла, таблица отказывается обновляться. Пробовал fireTableDataChanged() - не работает, причём только для кнопки загрузки. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Код интерфейса:

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class TestGUI extends JFrame{
    public PlaceList list = new PlaceList();
    PlaceList list0 = new PlaceList();
    public PlaceList tModel = list;
    public TestGUI(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JFrame menu = new JFrame();
        JFrame addVal = new JFrame();
        JFrame delVal = new JFrame();

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    JPanel table = new JPanel();
    JPanel adds = new JPanel();
    JPanel dell = new JPanel();

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Добавить элемент");
    JButton delButton = new JButton("Удалить элемент");
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Сохранить таблицу в файл");
    JButton loadButton = new JButton("Загрузить таблицу из файла");
    JButton showButton = new JButton("Вывести диаграмму");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Выход");
    JButton add1Val = new JButton("Добавить");
    JButton del1Val = new JButton("Удалить");

    JTextField planetField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField countryField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField cityField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField streetField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField houseField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField delField = new JTextField(5);

    JLabel planetLabel = new JLabel("Планета: ");
    JLabel countryLabel = new JLabel("Страна: ");
    JLabel cityLabel = new JLabel("Город:: ");
    JLabel streetLabel = new JLabel("Улица: ");
    JLabel houseLabel = new JLabel("Дом: ");
    JLabel delLine = new JLabel("Ведите номер рейса\n который хотите удалить");

    adds.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));
    adds.add(planetLabel);
    adds.add(planetField);
    adds.add(countryLabel);
    adds.add(countryField);
    adds.add(cityLabel);
    adds.add(cityField);
    adds.add(streetLabel);
    adds.add(streetField);
    adds.add(houseLabel);
    adds.add(houseField);
    adds.add(add1Val);

    dell.setLayout(new BoxLayout(dell, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    dell.add(delLine);
    dell.add(delField);
    dell.add(del1Val);

    JTable gps = new JTable(tModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gps);

    addVal.getContentPane().add(adds);
    delVal.getContentPane().add(dell);
    addVal.pack();
    delVal.pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            add1Val.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        list.addVal(planetField.getText(), countryField.getText(), cityField.getText(), streetField.getText(), houseField.getText());
                        tModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                        System.out.println(tModel.getValueAt(2,2));

                    }catch (Exception er){
                        er.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        addVal.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    delButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            del1Val.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{
                        list.rmvVal(Integer.parseInt(delField.getText()));
                        tModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                    }catch(Exception et){
                        et.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        delVal.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("places.json");
                gson.toJson(list, writer);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Список успешно сохранён.");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            String json = "";
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("places.json");
            list = gson.fromJson(reader, list.getClass());
            tModel.fireTableDataChanged();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Список успешно загружен.");
        }
        catch(Exception load){
            load.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });

    buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    buttons.add(addButton);
    buttons.add(delButton);
    buttons.add(saveButton);
    buttons.add(loadButton);
    buttons.add(showButton);

    table.add(scrollPane);

    menu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    menu.getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    menu.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    menu.pack();
    menu.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Код кнопки загрузки:

```
  loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String json = "";
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("places.json");
                list = gson.fromJson(reader, list.getClass());
                tModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Список успешно загружен.");
            }
            catch(Exception load){
                load.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
```

Элемент списка:

```
package GUI;

public class Place {
    private String earth, country, city, street, house;
    Place(){
        earth=null;
        country=null;
        city=null;
        street=null;
        house=null;
    }

    Place(String erth,String cntr,String ct,String str,String hs){
        earth=erth;
        country=cntr;
        city=ct;
        street=str;
        house=hs;
    }
    public String getEarth(){ return earth; }
    public String getCountry(){ return country; }
    public String getCity(){ return city; }
    public String getStreet(){ return street; }
    public String getHouse(){ return house; }

}
```

Код модели таблицы:

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlaceList extends AbstractTableModel {
    ArrayList<Place> PList = new ArrayList<Place>();

    PlaceList() {
        PList.add(new Place("Земля", "Япония", "Токио", "Улица", "55"));
        PList.add(new Place("Земля", "Россия", "Москва", "Улица", "66"));
        PList.add(new Place("Земля", "Австралия", "Канбера", "Улица", "77"));
    }

    void addVal(String erth, String cntr, String ct, String str, String hs) {
        PList.add(new Place(erth, cntr, ct, str, hs));
    }

    void rmvVal(int a) {
        PList.remove(a-1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return PList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int c) {
        String result = "";
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                result = "Планета";
                break;
            case 1:
                result = "Страна";
                break;
            case 2:
                result = "Город";
                break;
            case 3:
                result = "Улица";
                break;
            case 4:
                result = "Дом";
                break;
        }
        return result;

    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                return PList.get(r).getEarth();
            case 1:
                return PList.get(r).getCountry();
            case 2:
                return PList.get(r).getCity();
            case 3:
                return PList.get(r).getStreet();
            case 4:
                return PList.get(r).getHouse();
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        TestGUI a = new TestGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: строка `list = gson.fromJson(reader, list.getClass());` создает новый объект модели `PlaceList` и помещает ссылку на него в поле `list`. Ни старая модель, ни таблица, про этот объект ничего не знают. Вам надо или установить этот объект в таблицу, либо залить из него данные в старую модель